# latest OpenSSL version that supports SSLv3

Tags: openssl, sslv3

I need to update OpenSSL to the latest version that supports SSLv3. I need to know which is the latest OpenSSL version that supports SSLv3. On the openssl website I didn't find info about it.

Comment: All versions of OpenSSL support SSLv3, by default. An application using OpenSSL can disable it with `SSL_OP*` flags on the generic `SSLv23` methods, or by using newer-version method. Further, all versions of OpenSSL still support SSLv2 in the default build, but it is disabled at runtime unless the default cipherlist is changed to include SSL2-specific ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how it was compiled: take a look at the [build script](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/openssl&id=4b82ed4285c7cb76caf6d75a015c5a7542c625d1) from Arch Linux if you are interested.

So I think you should be able to compile from source without the `no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method` compile-time options if you want SSLv3 support.

If you are looking for a package, the last version that I know supported SSLv3 was `1.0.2f`, at least on Arch Linux.